# Retrieving a row number of a specific row from a group of rows in a table in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, rownum

I have a table named `USER_ROLES` in Oracle 10g as follows.

```
USER_ROLE_ID        USER_ID    AUTHORITY

28                  2          ROLE_ADMIN
45                  3          ROLE_USER
61                  3          ROLE_ASSISTANT
27                  3          ROLE_SUPERVISOR
```

Where `USER_ID` is a foreign key of the table `USER_TABLE`. I need to know a row number of a specific row from a group of rows associated with a specific user (`USER_ID`) (and not based on all the rows in this table).

---

The following SQL retrieves the row number for a given `USER_ROLE_ID` (28 in this case) based on **all** the rows in this table.

```
select row_num from 
(select row_number() over (order by user_role_id desc) as row_num, user_role_id 
from user_roles order by user_role_id desc)
where user_role_id=28
```

It displays 3, in this case.

---

But I need to retrieve the row number from a group of rows which is associated only with a particular user. For this to be so, if I try the following SQL,

```
select row_num from 
(select row_number() over (order by user_role_id desc) as row_num, user_role_id 
from user_roles order by user_role_id desc)
where user_id=2 and user_role_id=28
```

In this case, I have modified the `WHERE` clause from

```
where user_role_id=28
```

to

```
where user_id=2 and user_role_id=28
```

It gives the following error.

```
ORA-00904: "USER_ID": invalid identifier
```

So, what is the way to fetch a row number from only those rows which are associated with a specific user, in this scenario?

Comment: Well, you are getting the error because you are referencing a column that does not exist in your inline view or as a table in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add the user_id to the inner query. i think you also want to partition that analytic if you want the row_num to be per `user_id` (if not ignore that bit):

```
select row_num 
  from  (select row_number() over (partition by user_id 
                                   order by user_role_id desc) as row_num, 
                user_role_id, user_id
           from user_roles)
where user_role_id=28 and user_id = 2;
```